# What is so good about category theoy?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am interested in learning category theory, but I am concerned about its applications. I know its extremely important in functional programming but I want to know how this theory applies to the natural sciences like physics or biology etc. Moreover, how good is category theory in abstract theoretical mathematics? Why do we need this highly abstract theory in doing mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the books [*"Category Theory for Scientists"*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Category-Theory-Sciences-MIT-Press/dp/0262028131) and [*"Categories for the Working Mathematician*"](https://g.co/kgs/MpKnQP).